# Include minimum pip version in setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I've created a setup.py for my application. Some of the dependencies i set in install_requires require pip version 19.3.1 or greater.

Is there a way to check for pip version as part of setup.py? and to upgrade pip prior to build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not your responsibility to build workarounds in your project for the issues in the packaging of other projects. This is kind of a bad practice. There is also not much point in doing this as part of a `setup.py` anyway since in many cases this file is not executed during *install time*.

The best thing you can do is try and fix the faulty packaging of these dependency projects directly: contact the maintainers, file an issue, propose a fix, etc.

The second best thing is to inform the users of your project. Clearly state this problem in the documentation of your own project and how to prevent it (i.e. "install *pip* version *19.3.1* or greater").

---

**Update**:

If you decide to enforce a check in `setup.py` anyway, here are some techniques that might help...

But I would still recommend against those, since your `setup.py` is not actually at fault here, but the issue seems to lie in the packaging of the dependencies.

**1.**

```
__requires__ = ['pip >= 19.3.1']  # make sure it's before 'import setuptools'
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    # ...
)
```

This would trigger an exception:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip>=19.3.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

The drawback of this technique is that it doesn't trigger when called from *pip* (for example: `pip install .`), since in that case the `__main__` module is not `setup.py` but a module of *pip*.

Reference:

- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pkg_resources.html?highlight=requires#workingset-objects

**2.**

```
import pkg_resources
import setuptools

pkg_resources.require(['pip >= 19.3.1'])

setuptools.setup(
    # ...
)
```

This would trigger a `pkg_resources.VersionConflict` exception.

This should work even if called from *pip*, but...

This doesn't seem to work with *build isolation* (*PEP 517*, `pyproject.toml`), because in such a case there is usually no *pip* at all in the build environment.

Reference:

- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pkg_resources.html?highlight=require#basic-workingset-methods

Comment: My old version of `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.7)` was pulling dependencies from pypi due to identical private package name even if I had remote GitHub location explicitly specified. After wasting my morning to debug the installation issue, I noticed that the latest pip downloads the package from external link nicely without any weird side effects. I don't see how it would be an bad practice to fail early to a known pip issue.

Comment: Not sure I understood the whole comment. -- On failing early: yes, I guess it's acceptable in `setup.py` to somehow check _pip_'s version number and fail if it's not in the expected range (maybe with `__requires__ = ['pip >= 19.3.1']; import setuptools` at the top of `setup.py`). The question also asked about upgrading _pip_ from within `setup.py` which would be highly unlikely to work reliably.

Comment: Agreed, auto installation is bad.

Comment: I tried adding `__requires__ = ['pip >= 21.3.1']` on top of my `setup.py` but at least in my case it did not fail.

Comment: @Jaako, I am surprised it didn't fail. What command did you call? It should fail for example on `path/to/pythonX.Y setup.py`. I believe it won't fail if you call _pip_.

Comment: I did `pip install .` on the directory with `setup.py`. "I believe it won't fail if you call pip", yes this was exactly what I did :D.

Comment: Yes, that's a limitation of the `__requires__` method. In this case, this value is not checked because the `__main__` module is not `setup.py`, that would probably be _pip_ in this case.

Comment: @Jaakko I added another technique to my answer that should trigger a failure even if called from _pip_.