# How to specify a minimum pip version with a dependency specification?

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

[PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) describes how to set additional specifications for dependencies. This can be used for example to specify that a dependency should only be installed on Linux systems.

Is there any way to use this syntax to specify a minumum `pip` version for a package?

My use case: one dependency is built with [`manylinux2010`](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) and requires `pip` >= 19.0. I would like the dependency to be installed when `pip` >= 19.0, and ignored otherwise. This is different from [Include minimum pip version in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068313/include-minimum-pip-version-in-setup-py?noredirect=1&lq=1) where the author wants to restrict the `pip` version for the whole project.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is possible. At least not in any reasonable straightforward way that I can think of. You will just have to assume that the users of your project have an up to date _pip_ and you will have to correctly document your project to explicitly state that _pip_ has to be up to date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include minimum pip version in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068313/include-minimum-pip-version-in-setup-py)

Comment: Thanks for linking this question! It is similar, but I would like to just ignore this specific dependency if the pip version requirement is not met, and not raise an exception. Looks like I could manually check the pip version in `setup.py` and conditionally add the dependency in `install_requires`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Alternative: you could make this dependency optional, i.e. make it part of an _extra_, for example with setuptools: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You could make an ugly hack like this in `setup.py`:

```py
import pkg_resources
import setuptools

install_requires = [
    # ...
]

try:
    pip_dist = pkg_resources.get_distribution('pip')
except:
    pass
else:
    if pip_dist.parsed_version > pkg_resources.parse_version('19'):
        install_requires.append('Library')

setuptools.setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=install_requires,
)
```

This is written off the top of my head (pseudo code), untested, tweaking will most likely be required.

I definitely would not recommend doing this, this has lots of red flags, goes against many best practice recommendations.

Most importantly the condition on pip's version number will not be respected as soon as *build isolation* is involved or if installing from a *wheel* (wheels do not contain the `setup.py` file).

Answer (score 0):

In your setup.py, add the below snippet before anything.

**Code:**

```py
import pip

if pip.__version__ < '19':
    raise RuntimeError('Required pip>=19.0 to install')

import spam
import foo
...
...
setup(...)
```

This will check if the pip dependency is maintained or not.

Comment: This will not work when installing from a _wheel_, since it does not include the `setup.py`.